# Увеличение изображение в виджете Posts - Elementor - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Добавил в страницу виджет Posts от Elemenotor
Мне нужно чтобы при наведение на картинку новости он немного увеличился в масштабах. Не могу найти свойство hover для картинки новости.
Как это можно сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С помощью какого плагина? Это элементор ПРО или другой плагин? У нас нет доступа к Вашей странице и настройкам, ну и телепатов тут нет. А по существу - смотрите, какой класс у картинки и пишите стиль на ХОВЕР -> ЗУМ (желательно плавный)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку у Вас ElementorPro, то можно добавить на закладке расширение в блок Custom CSS? следующий стиль:

```
.elementor-posts-container.elementor-has-item-ratio .elementor-post__thumbnail img:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03) translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.03) translate(-50%,-50%) ;
    transform: scale(1.03) translate(-50%,-50%) ;
}
```

Естественно сдвиг и масштаб устанавливаете так, как Вам надо.

Можно ещё добавить следующий код, что бы увеличение было плавней:

```
    .elementor-posts-container.elementor-has-item-ratio .elementor-post__thumbnail img{
    -webkit-transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
    transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
}
```

До ховера.